# C# Windows Service works locally and server says it is running, but nothing happens and no errors are thrown

Tags: c#, .net, io, windows-services

I have a windows service that reads in .csv files, parses and stores their contents in a database, and then moves the files over to a new location for storage and so they aren't reprocessed. I have this service set to run in Interactive Mode locally as a console app, so when I test it in debug mode everything works perfectly. The files are read and moved over.

When I start the service on the server, however, it runs... and nothing happens. Files are not read into the database and nothing is moved. Below is the code that is doing he heavy lifting, sanitized somewhat.

```
private void ImportFiles()
{
    try
    {
        var directory = new DirectoryInfo("\\\\server\\vol2\\Accounting\\Public\\files to import");
        var processedFilesDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("\\\\server\\vol2\\Accounting\\Public\\files to import\\Processed Files");
        var directories = directory.GetDirectories();
        foreach (var directoryInfo in directories)
        {
            if (directoryInfo.Name != "Processed Files" || directoryInfo.Name != "ErrorLog")
            {
                var files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
                foreach (var fileInfo in files)
                {
                    var Lines = File.ReadLines(fileInfo.FullName);
                    var csv = from line in Lines select (line.Split(',')).ToArray();
                    var entriesToImport = BuildFileEntries(csv);
                    SaveNewEntries(entriesToImport);
                    File.Move(fileInfo.FullName, processedFilesDirectory + "\\" + fileInfo.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogErrors(e);
    }
}
```

The server reports that the service is running, and there are no errors being generated.

Comment: Does your server have all the directories you are trying to use in your code? What calls this method `ImportFiles()`? Maybe add a test block of code to write a text file when entering the method and another inside the if statement of your for loop, see if either of those execute.

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions issue? Any errors being logged? Are you using a local or domain user account? Or the LocalSystem account?

Comment: @RyanWilson The server should have access to these directories, yes. There are other services on this server that are accessing other directories on this same drive and they work just fine. `ImportFiles()` is called by a 'Timer' in my service when it elapses. I will try adding in those writes and see what happens.

Comment: @RuiJarimba there are no errors being logged unfortunately. On the server, the service is being run using a dedicated account for windows services.

Comment: @CthuluHoop I meant are you sure these directories exist on the server? If so, I think testing it with the writing of a text file may help to see if your code is even executing.

Comment: @RyanWilson just tested it. Locally the file writes to the location just fine. From the server the file does not write to the location. It looks like my code might not even be executing even though the server says it is running.

Comment: @CthuluHoop Well, at least you narrowed it down. I hope that it helps you find the issue.